# Android Studio not seeing module classes from Maven module project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have 2 projects that are based on Maven. They compile perfectly with Maven. I've imported these projects into Android Studio and I'm having dependency issues. I first created an Android Studio project for my module by importing the Maven pom.xml. This module compiles correctly in Android Studio. I then created another Android Studio project for my main project by importing the pom.xml. I then choose File > Import Module and imported my newly created Android Studio MODULE project.

My main project will not compile in Android Studio consistently. It always has problems seeing the classes in the module. It, somehow, compiled ONCE. Now, I try to rebuild the project and I'm getting the same errors again.

Project structure is like this:

```
-Project A
-- src/MainActivity.java
-Module A
-- src/... (a bunch of code)
-- dependency 1
-- dependency 2
-- dependency 3
etc..
```

The errors are essentially:

```
error: package com.mysite.myclass does not exist
```

com.mysite.myclass does exist because I can compile my project with Maven. com.mysite.myclass comes from a dependency in Module A (not Module A's actual src). Further, I can see the classes in question in the Project file navigator under External Libraries > dependency X > src/

Comment: Use `Gradle` with Android Studio, or convert your maven project to gradle

Comment: @LalithB - I'm not the project lead and cannot move it off of Maven. Maven is for an automated build environment.